# Laravel API endpoint with non-primitive type hinted parameter

Tags: php, laravel, uuid

I have an API endpoint that I want to pass a UUID to.  I am using a package called [Laravel-UUID](https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid) to integrate UUID's into my application.  I would like my API endpoints that take a UUID to automatically parse the parameter as a `Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid` type instead of a `string` that I have to manually convert to a `Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid` in each of my endpoints.  Is there a way in Laravel to make it attempt to parse any route parameter named `{uuid}` from a `string` to a `Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid`?

**web.php**

`Route::get('/mycontroller/test/{uuid}', 'Web\MyController@test')->name('test');`

**MyController.php**

```
use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;

...

public function test(Request $request, Uuid $uuid): RedirectResponse
{
    echo 'My UUID: ' . $uuid->string;

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

I am attempting to call the above code via a URL like:

`http://localhost:8000/mycontroller/test/9ec21125-6367-1ab3-9c88-d6de3990ff81`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: **model binding**.

Add to `boot()` method in your `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`:

```php
Route::bind('uuid', function ($value) {
    return Uuid::import($value);
});
```

And when you access `{uuid}` in from your route you will get Uuid object, like:

```php
Route::get('test/{uuid}', function($uuid) {

    echo $uuid->string;

});
```

Comment: I had tried that previously, but I get the following error: "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message". I had ran `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan clear-compiled` too with no. luck.

Comment: How you're accessing this URL?

Comment: In my original question, I posted the URL I am using.  I am copying and pasting it into my browser.

Comment: Try to change your route to ANY: `Route::any('/mycontroller/test/{uuid}', 'Web\MyController@test')->name('test');`

Comment: Just noticed that, and it works!  Do I have to implement all the code for that endpoint inside of the route in `web.php` or can I can I implement it in `MyController.php`'s `test` function?

Comment: Better way is implement your code in controller - your routes can be cached, this is more proper way.

Comment: I didn't follow, which is the better way?  Code in controller, or code in routes?  If I put all my code in the routes wouldn't my `web.php` file get rather out of hand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171873/discussion-between-daniel-and-roundtheworld).